# .Net core windows service not processing one of my method

Tags: windows-services, .net-core

```
public class Operations_Collection
{
static Alerts alert = new Alerts();
private ILogger logger;

private Timer _timer;

private readonly AlertsDataBaseContext _context = new AlertsDataBaseContext();

UpdateDatabase updateDataBase = new UpdateDatabase();

SendMail _sendEmailcs = new SendMail(alert);

private static readonly object Locker = new object();

private string fileName = Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "Oparation.txt");

public void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

    File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("------------ {0}\n", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")));

    lock (Locker)
    {

        File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("Inside locker--------", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")));
        Console.WriteLine("Working.....");


        if (true)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("inside if--------", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")));
 -------->     List<Alerts> alertList = GetList();
            File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("inside if--------", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")+"alertlistcount====="+alertList.Count+"--------"));
            foreach (var alert in alertList)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("inside foreach--------", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")));
                _sendEmailcs.Send(alert);

                try
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("inside try--------", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")));
                    updateDataBase.Update(alert.AlertId, _sendEmailcs.Statement);
                }

                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
private List<Alerts> GetList()
{

      File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("inside getlist--------", DateTime.Now.ToString() ));
 -------> var mylist = _context.Alerts.Where(x => x.IsMailSent == false).ToList();
    File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("GetList middle--------", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")+mylist.Count));
    var top3Query = mylist.OrderBy(x => x.AlertId).Take(3);

    File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("end of getlist--------", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")+top3Query.Count()));
    return top3Query.ToList();

   }
}
```

I have a .Net core console application that intented to work as a windows service. It works as console app perfectly. But when I passed it to windows service, it stuck inside one of my methods. It is GetList method, I showed with arrows inside code. The last thing app is doing is writing in a text file that "inside GetList"(you can check GetList method for this). I used [this](https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService) nuget package for my purpose. Please help; Why it is not processing that method even if it gets inside that method?

Comment: can you put a try/catch around it? it is a database call and subject to DB connection timeouts (can be 30-60 seconds)

Comment: Ahh sorry I forget try catch. Now ı tried with it and the problem was the database connection. Full error is "Cannot open database "AlertsDataBase" requested by the login. The login failed". Sorry for bother you.By the way thanks a lot for illuminating me.